# Index "server_name" not exist

Tags: php, variables, constants, global

I try to execute a bat, and in this file i try to acceed to this variable :

`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

But it doesn't exist this index. In fact, when i try to `print_r($_SERVER)`, there is no  `SERVER_NAME` index. There is a reason ? Is it because i launch this function in a bat ? 
Have I an other solution for get this variable ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$_SERVER` variables are only available in a server environment (hosting PHP through Apache or another web server), so if you are launching it from the command line they won't be available. The parameters of this object are populated by the HTTP headers, which in your case don't exist.

If you want to ignore the `$_SERVER` object when the `SERVER_NAME` isn't set, you can alternative use `php_uname("n")` but your mileage may vary depending on operating system.

```
$server_name = (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))? // check if SERVER_NAME is set
    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] :                    // if yes, use HTTP header value
    php_uname("n");                             // if no, use php_uname()
```

Comment: Ok, but it's available, just it's not return "server_name" in his array ... There is an other way to get this ? Thanks !

Comment: The object exists, but it won't be populated without HTTP headers which only come about if there is an HTTP request.

Comment: I understand ! Well, there is no function which can get that ... I would like to create a link in a mail. So in my template i have a <a href="">. There is a bat who make a variable who contains this link and inert in the template. But how can i make this link if i can't get the Server_Name ?

Comment: You want to get the hostname of your computer? Your best bet is probably to use `$hostname = php_uname("n");` but this might work differently on different operating systems.

Comment: I don't think it's the hostname ... For example, this is the url : http://bestsiteevernevercreated.com/index/image.png . I would like to get in the php file which is executed by the bat file the constant : bestsiteevernervercreate.com , the server name no ? (i will try php_uname)

Comment: php_uname("n") doesn't display the good value and i can't do gethostname(), i have php 5.2

Comment: You don't have too many option then unfortunately... best bet might be to just hard code it into a config file.

Comment: Yes probably ... Thx a lot to have try to help me !

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo %COMPUTERNAME%
```

instead if you are launching through a bat-file.

Answer (score 0):

The `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` variable holds the name of the server as supplied by the HTTP client in the *Host* HTTP header field. Because you do not use HTTP, this variable is not defined.